# QGIS 2.14 fails while booting-up

Tags: qgis, osgeo4w

I installed QGIS 2.14 on a Windows7 64bit via the installer. But QGIS can not boot up remaining "Restoring loaded plugins...".

Although I re-installed it after I un-installed all of QGIS software including older versions and removed QGIS-related folders and registory key once from the pc, the 2.14 still can not boot up.

Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: I removed all python plugin files in the following folder and then restart. It works finally.      C:\Program Files\QGIS Essen\apps\qgis\python\plugins

Answer (score 1):

Plugins are installed under User.qgis2\python\plugins.

If the origin of the problem is in the plugins, you could try and rename the original .qgis2 folder and restart QGIS. When this works, you can restore items from the old folder or reconfigure / reinstall through QGIS itself.